# How to exclude lines that contain a hyphen in them using Python's re module?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

From the input, I would like to print out lines that start with small letters ("hum") and end with "0001". Furthermore, I would like to exclude lines that contain a hyphen in them (in the example, exclude the last two lines from the current output).

My guess is to include `[^-\s]` in the regular expression which means to exclude the lines with hyphens, but it's not working.

**Input**

```
humabddd001
humhudiwhde001
rehfhfepfhfpehr001oifdjv
iurehfehofewoh001
jfeijjjrefoefojrefoj001
humfiowhewiwihowfhiowfeoewo991
hum0001ofejofrjwoorejfoejfo001
foiwejowjfojfojwofwofjew9032i92i
humifhihweoowhefiwofowfo001
Humerfhofrorr001
HUmhuhdeowhdoewh000001
HUMwifoiewjow001
0001fhdisuhum
hUmfhweoofhwfoh001
humhum001hum
humhumhufih001
humifwje001001
hum30204-439-0942-4029-0001
humouio--hohohoho0001
```

**My Code**

```
import re
hand = open('D:/Python/Test.txt')
x = hand
for j in x:
     h = re.findall('hum.*\S+001+$',j)
#    h = re.findall('hum+\S+001+$',j)
     if(len(h)>0):
          print(h)
```

**My Current Output**

```
['humabddd001']
['humhudiwhde001']
['hum0001ofejofrjwoorejfoejfo001'] 
['humifhihweoowhefiwofowfo001']
['humhumhufih001']
['humifwje001001']
['hum30204-439-0942-4029-0001']
['humouio--hohohoho0001']
```

Comment: This isn't really a regex problem: `if line.startswith('hum') and line.endswith('001') and '-' not in line: print(line)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are adding the *negated character class* `[^-\s]` to a pattern already containing `.*`, a greedy dot pattern that matches **any** 0 or more characters other than a newline. `.*\S+` will match any chars other than newline and then the last non-whitespace char (the `+` after `\S` is redundant in this case).

Another issue is that `re.findall` searches for matches *anywhere* inside the string, but you only need a match at the start of the line. So, you need to add `^` anchor at the pattern start, or use `re.match` method.

Here is a fix for your approach:

```
results = [j for j in x if re.search(r'^hum[^-\s]*001$', j)]
# => ['humabddd001', 'humhudiwhde001', 'hum0001ofejofrjwoorejfoejfo001', 'humifhihweoowhefiwofowfo001', 'humhumhufih001', 'humifwje001001']
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/Qwq3Un) and the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kC7AAn/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `hum` - a literal substring
- `[^-\s]*` - 0 or more `-` or whitespace chars
- `001` - a `001` literal substring
- `$` - end of string.

And as Patricks says, you do not really need a regex *unless* you want to easily handle all Unicode whitespace. In that case, you might use

```
no_regex_results = [j for j in x if j.startswith('hum') and j.endswith('001') and '-' not in j and ' ' not in j]
```

It is a bit longer and does not handle Unicode whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regexp: `^hum[^-]*001$`

Output:

```
['humabddd001']
['humhudiwhde001']
['hum0001ofejofrjwoorejfoejfo001']
['humifhihweoowhefiwofowfo001']
['humhumhufih001']
['humifwje001001']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
hand = open('D:/Python/Test.txt')
x = hand

for j in x:
     h = re.findall('^hum[^-]*0001$',j)

     if(len(h)>0):
          print(h)
```

And as said by @Patrick Haugh, this doesn't need Regex. Proper use of `startswith`, `endswith` and `not in` will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use regex at all here.  Your requirements fall neatly in existing string methods, and aren't complex enough to require a regex.

```
with open('Test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith('hum') and line.endswith('001') and '-' not in line:
            print(line)
```

prints

```
humabddd001
humhudiwhde001
hum0001ofejofrjwoorejfoejfo001
humifhihweoowhefiwofowfo001
humhumhufih001
humifwje001001
```